# How to enable Startup Sound in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, startup, lts, startup-applications

**Commands on internet for enabling Startup Sound works only on older builds of Ubuntu like 20.04. Therefore please provide a command in order to enable it for 22.04.1 LTS.**

Comment: I've always just use `paplay`, and it's worked from 10.10 (*maverick*) through to my current *lunar* install (ie. what will be 23.04 on release).  My system only recently switched from PulseAudio to PipeWire, and I didn't notice it stop working with that either.  ie. no change of command was required for my only installs from Ubuntu 10.10 through to current *development* release of Ubuntu *lunar* (what will be 23.04 on release).  What's your issue exactly?

Comment: @guiverc I found a more reliable method as: `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"`
This directly configures within the system that startup sound is to be played. idk why but paplay didn't seem to function on my system!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The ***description*** in the above **image** is to be *copied* as it is in "**Startup Application**".